# how to style specific links in css

Tags: html, css

Do you know how to style specific links? I put my code so that every link will have a transition of 0.400 ms for the font to grow a bit bigger when the mouse cursor hovers over it. But the problem is that I have another link that is 30px big and when I hover over it, it turns to 18px because every single a href in  tag has that, but how can I change it?

```css
.link_2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link_1" href="#">Text that's normal</a>
<a class="link_2" href="#">Text with problem</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Change the `a:hover` to specific

- That is Change the `a:hover` to `.link_1:hover`

```css
.link_2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link_1:hover {/*Changed here*/
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link_1" href="#">Text that's normal</a>
<a class="link_2" href="#">Text with problem:Solved</a>
```